# RewriteCond being met in testing but not in practice

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [C]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*).php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I want it to firstly reroute everything to HTTPS.

Then I want to check if the user is accessing a PHP file, such as `domain.com/pages/page/a.php` and route that to `/index.php`.

Then lastly I want everything thats not a file or a directory to route to `index.php` such as `domain.com/my-fun-page`

I think the first and the last blocks are correct, but for some reason when I run a test on [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) It works successfully.  However when I run it on my own server it still lets me access `domain.com/pages/page/a.php`.

How can I find out why, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below for php part,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your 2nd a 3rd rule into a single rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,LE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Even `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f [OR]` may not be necessary as `!-f` and `!-d` will already cover this case.